# App Inventor-how to link from page in my site to page in my app?

Tags: app-inventor

In the title.
App Inventor-how to link from page in my site to page in my app? contact page

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a WebView:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xC4w.png)

Of course, replace the Homeurl with your contact page.